# '-gate' as a suffix to coin words related to scandals and corruption cases

Tags: word-usage, etymology, american-english, suffixes

I noticed that for corrruption/scandals the usage of '-gate' suffix is pretty common, as we have recently seen with 'datagate' and before with 'watergate'

Can anyone explain what the relation between '-gate' and scandals is and why this relation arose? Also, is this '-gate' used with the same sense in British English, too?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-gate

Comment: @RegD., as for your knowledge, in case you didn't read that page, there is also a scandal interestingly called 'biscuitgate'.

Comment: When iPhone 4 was launched it had a problem that makes the phone lose signal. It was known as AntennaGate.

Comment: Hey Vitor - there are literally 1000s of examples.  **Climategate** was I guess the actually biggest "real scandal" where the -gate term was used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It comes from the [Watergate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal) scandal.

Comment: I heard that *-gate* itself was the creation of a conservative commentator, who thought that having the media talk about such things as *Housegate, Cakegate* and *Gategate* (all of which I have seen in earnest) would reduce the impact of *Watergate* itself. Can't find a source at present (which is why this is a comment), but whether true or not, the suffix has certainly taken on a life of its own.

Comment: Tim, that sounds pretty silly i'd say - i doubt that's the case. Just an urban legend. (Indeed, note the info from the OED courtesy Andrew.)

Comment: @TimLymington Possibly from [Etymology, usage, and history of -gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scandals_with_%22-gate%22_suffix#Etymology.2C_usage.2C_and_history_of_-gate) from the Wikipedia article "List of scandals with "-gate" suffix".

Answer (score 30):

All these formations are modeled after the [Watergate scandal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal) which you mentioned. That scandal, in turn, took its name from the very innocently named [Watergate Complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_building), a group of buildings in Washington DC which happened to house the office which housed the documents that were stolen as part of the [Watergate Burglaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_burglaries), and thus ended up giving its name (or at least half of it) to various political scandals for nearly half a century since.

The suffix itself doesn't have anything to do with scandal, intrinsically. It's the association with the famous Watergate scandal that gave it its new meaning.

Comment: What I find interesting today, is that young people generally don't know this connection, having no reference to Watergate.

Do you all think this use of "-gate" will soon disappear because of this, the lack of appreciation of Watergate?
Or will the use of "-gate" end up educating the next generation about Watergate?

Comment: I like the way phrases, images and other symbols get a life of their own, distinct from their origins. A rotary phone's circular dial-pad lives on as a symbol for telephones, while a floppy disk symbolizes Save, even for kids who have never actually used any of those. The -Gate will live on.

Comment: @MikeM, etymology doesn’t play much of a role in the use of words and, especially, suffixes. For example, very few English speakers today know that the suffix _-ly_, used to make adjectives and adverbs, is originally a noun that means ‘corpse’ (or more generally, ‘shape, form’)—cognate with ‘like’ and the word _lych_ ‘corpse’ that, quite apropos, is mainly used in the term _lychgate_ ‘roofed gateway into a churchyard’. The fact that few people know of this etymology and connection has of course never stopped anyone from using it all over the place.

Comment: [What if there's a scandal about water? What do you call that?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB9JgxhXW5w)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet -  indeed, I did not know that! :)

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan -  indeed!  Good point.  I love the floppy disk reference.

Comment: It's an interesting curiosity that "gate", sort of kind of suggests something about a scandal: it makes you think of (say) information "passing through" something.  It's a stretch but there's kind of a feeling there.  As Mike points out, young people are so uneducated they don't know Watergate was just a hotel name in the Nixon era.  (Indeed they don't even know what a "Nixon" is.) So the formation will probably be quite confused in the future.

Comment: I'd love there to be another scandal relating to Watergate, and then watch journalists implode as they try to work out what to call it.

Comment: I'd love it if all the documents relating to the Watergate scandal were somehow stolen in suspicious circumstances, leading to a Watergategate

Comment: @RoundTower - I'd guess it would come to be known as Aquagate or Hydrogate.

Comment: @PhilMJones They would call it "Watergate II" or ... <sorry, much worse> "Watergate 2.0".

Answer (score 5):

As other answers have noted, the first scandal ending in "-gate" was the Watergate scandal.

The Oxford English Dictionary [says](http://public.oed.com/aspects-of-english/english-in-use/the-gate-suffix/) that other scandals having "-gate" tacked on happened reasonably quickly:

> Only a year after Watergate, the scandal had become so well known that *-gate* became detached and was used to create names for other scandals. The *OED*’s first recorded example is from August 1972 in *National Lampoon*:
>
> > ‘There have been persistent rumors in Russia of a vast scandal... Implicated in “the Volgagate” are a group of liberal officials.’
>
> A few months later the *-gate* craze had shown no signs of abating, a fact signalled by the weary use of ‘inevitably’ in the following quotation:
>
> > ‘Inevitably, the brouhaha of Bordeaux became known as Wine-gate.’

Comment: fantastic factual information

Comment: Interesting extract form BBC Magazine News : http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-22464422