# -gate, and gamergate

Tags: suffixes, neologisms, descriptive-grammar

I have always understood the phrase ____-gate to refer to a controversy or conflict. For example, deflate-gate was the hubbub around whether the Patriots intentionally deflated balls during the AFC Championship. **The original, Watergate, was a scandal under the Nixon administration.**

**However, I hear references to people being pro-gamergate or anti-gamergate.** This seems to imply that gamergate is not a description of a controversy or conflict, but rather, of only one side of some conflict.

**Under my understanding, it wouldn't make sense to call somebody pro-watergate, or anti-watergate. You'd have to say pro-Nixon or anti-Nixon.**

**Is gamergate used in a non-standard way as compared to other -gates?** If so, how did this come about?

---

Edit: Twice now, I've been presented with a banner saying "This question may already have an answer here:
Why do we use the suffix “‑gate” when referring to a scandal? [closed] 3 answers" It gives me an option: "No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how." So, I'm editing to explain how my question is different.

I **am not** asking *why* we use the suffix "-gate" when referring to a scandal. I give the etymology of that use in my question, so there is no way you could construe my question as asking why we use the suffix "-gate" when referring to a scandal. I'm asking: given that we use the suffix "-gate" when referring to a scandal, is the use of terms like "pro-gamergate" non-standard as compared to previous uses? The answerer and a few commenters got exactly what I was asking. This question generated an answer *different* than the type of answer the other "duplicate" answer generated. Those other questions were not sufficient to address this novel sense of the "-gate" suffix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we use the suffix “‑gate” when referring to a scandal?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36800/why-do-we-use-the-suffix-gate-when-referring-to-a-scandal)

Comment: @Ronan How is this a duplicate? I state in the question *why* we usually use the suffix "-gate" when referring to a scandal. I'm asking whether the use of the word "gamergate" in language like "pro-gamergate" or "anti-gamergate" fits into that framework, and if not (as I suspect it doesn't), how it became an exception.

Comment: The Watergate scandal was named after the break-in at the [Watergate hotel and Office Building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_complex#Watergate_Hotel_and_Office_Building).

Comment: @IanMacDonald I know.

Comment: Understand that, after "Watergate", all the "-gate" names for scandals have been invented terms -- there's no English "rule" that controls this.  So anyone is free to invent "icecreamgate" and then "uber-icecreamgate" and then "goober-icecreamgate", or whatever they want.  There are no rules, and just because it maybe (kinda sorta) makes sense to say "goober-icecreamgate" does not imply that "goober" would have any sort of equivalent meaning when applied to "applepiegate".

Comment: @HotLicks I do understand that. I'm not looking for a rule. I'm asking if the use of gamergate is non-standard compared to previous uses of the -gate suffix, and for a bit of background as to how this new usage came to be. The current answer gets into that. Also, in your example, would pro-icecreamgate mean anything? That would be more in-line with what I'm asking.

Comment: How can it be "non-standard" when there is no standard?

Comment: @HotLicks Non-standard **compared to previous uses of the -gate suffix**. Read my entire sentences please. See these previous answers for a description of how it has been used until gamergate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36800/why-do-we-use-the-suffix-gate-when-referring-to-a-scandal, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144673/gate-as-a-suffix-to-coin-words-related-to-scandals-and-corruption-cases?rq=1 If you don't understand the question, you can ignore it. Others have understood it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gamergate was initially about a scandal, one in which there was an **alleged** affair between a games developer and a games journalist.

The 'scandal' that is alluded to is the supposed ethical complications of such a relationship, and whether or not it is acceptable for someone in a particular industry (in this case gaming) to have a personal relationship with someone who is supposed to be impartial within that industry when reviewing games.

This spawned a hashtag on twitter #gamergate, in order to raise awareness of the closeness between developers and journalists in gaming.

The hashtag #gamergate then became a general rallying cry for activists to make allegations against games developers and journalists who they believed were breaching gaming ethics.

So the word gamergate that is used now simply stems from the original scandal, but is now a word used to identify with something that has evolved beyond the scandal.

---

I won't go into any further detail, because I could stir up a lot of controversies about the debate between *pro-gamergate* and *anti-gamergate*.

This is not a statement on gamergate itself or what it may or may not represent, but let me state as a disclaimer that this is simply an impartial answer stating the facts to a specific question about the origins of a word. Hence the word *alleged*.

---

To go back to the OP, you can't be pro- or anti- scandal. The pro- or anti- is based on the movement that followed the *alleged* scandal.

For example, you can be pro- or anti-feminism, which is a movement.

You cannot be pro- or anti-20th century, that is just a thing that happened.

Comment: Which side is generally labelled (or self-identified as) pro-gamergate?

Comment: To be pro-gamergate is to be a supporter of sexism in video game culture.

Comment: Just to confirm then, this is a usage that doesn't conform to the standard usage of the -gate suffix?

Comment: Pro-gamergate is the side that agrees with the argument that game developers and journalists are too close personally. However the movement has evolved beyond that now. I won't go into detail because that discussion does not belong on this site. I would link further reading, but I'm unlikely to find a site that has an impartial view, and would not want to influence any outside reader's decision on it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking for details of the controversy, but being able to articulate (whether accurately or not) what the pro-gamergate "side" *is* tends to support my initial hunch that this instance of -gate is used in a different way than most others I've encountered.

Comment: Originally it did, but the word has evolved, and doesn't generally refer to that anymore. It can when you're mentioning the origins of the scandal. Despite your views of pro- or anti-gamergate, it's a very interesting case study on how language adapts its meaning so quickly in our modern society.

Comment: I thought gamergate was about sexism in video game culture (as @IanMacDonald implies). But the gaming journalism ethics is part of that story. I think the OPs question is about what it means to be pro- or anti-X-gate. whatever X-gate might be.

Comment: The "Pro" side views the controversy as stemming from problems with game journalism.  The "Anti" side views the controversy as stemming from sexism on the part of gamers.  It's a real mess because the two sides are arguing about completely different things.

Comment: Hey all, I don't actually need *more* descriptions of what the pro-side thinks. Just the fact that there *is* one or more articulable descriptions of a pro-side is sufficient.

Comment: "you can't be pro- or anti- scandal"  Actually, a lot of people are pro-scandal.

Comment: This is not a simple statement of the facts, it is taking the side that GamerGate was about ethical concerns. It was about harassment and hostility to people who didn't fit the standard anonymous/gamer stereotype.

Answer (score 0):

[**GamerGate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamergate_controversy) was coined when a number of journalists pointed out how toxic "gamer" culture had become, citing the harassment of women as the primary example. They pointed out that half if players are now female, and that they were of the opinion that it was time for the toxic "gamer" culture to go away.

Mike's answer is incorrect. The phrase was coined in a tweet by actor Adam Baldwin, in response to the above criticism. Before that point it was simply the harassment of women.

So, the scandal that GamerGate refers to is the reaction against the actions of self proclaimed "gamers" who harassed women.

The pro/anti labels came about because the core of the GamerGate movement started a fake "ethics in gaming" angle, mostly using sock puppet accounts. Some people fell for the deception and joined what they thought was a legitimate cause. Thus the pro group consists of misogynists and people with genuine (if exaggerated) ethical concerns. The anti group is opposed to harassment.

So this is an interesting case where there was a scandal (harassment), but the people doing the scandalous behaviour tried to take control of the narrative by owning the name. Thus, the -gate suffix is somewhat awkward.

Comment: can you provide some citation to support this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamergate_controversy